# Spring boot flyway scripts from dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot, flyway

As few of my modules use same flyway scripts I have extracted it to separated jar module. 
So now I just import this dependency and question is how to set flyway locations to search for those scripts ?

```
 spring.flyway.locations=classpath:migration-scripts-1.0-SNAPSHOT/db/migrations
```

??

Answer (score 0):

In our spring-boot project (2.1.3.RELEASE) we simply add the jar as dependency and it works, without specifying any location (in any jars).

Using

```
spring.flyway.locations=db/migrations
```

should work too. But if you are using default location db/migration/ (in migration-scripts-1.0-SNAPSHOT) then you can ignore this setting and simply not configure anything at all, since [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M5/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-execute-flyway-database-migrations-on-startup) states that default setting is classpath:db/migration and this seems to include location in dependency.